# Complex Coefficients and Real roots

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

Find $m$ which is a real number so that this equation has a real root.

$2z^2-(3+8i)z-(m+4i)=0$

I've tried $b^2-4ac=0 $ but I can only seem to get complex $m$ values, so either I'm missing a key point or just failing with my calculations.

Any help/ideas would really be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you include your trial using $b^2-4ac=0$, so that it might be easier for other people to help you?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If $z$ has to be real and as $m$ is also real,

equating the real & the imaginary parts

$$2z^2-3z-m=0$$

and $$8z+4=0$$

Comment: I did try this earlier and got m = 9/8 which seemed reasonable but the question was worth 20 marks so I thought there might be something more that I missed. But I guess not, thank you :)

Comment: @ N.K. If you got $m=9/8$, you might want to recalculate.